# IAX2 Trunks between PBXs - Moving from g729 to Opus codec - Is it worth upgrading the phones?

Tags: asterisk, opus, g729

I currently have 4 different physical locations, each running plain Asterisk 14.6.0, and using Digium D40 phones with the G729 codec. All the locations are connected via OpenVPN using IAX2 and the G729 codec. We use a separate regular cable modem (2MB) internet connection dedicated for each PBX, so that the VOIP traffic is not competing with regular internet usage.

I've read about how wonderul the opus codec is, and I'm planning on changing the IAX2 trunks between the PBXs to use opus instead of G729. However, the Digium D40 phones don't support the opus codec natively, so the PBX would have to transcode opus <-> G729.

Is it worth upgrading the phones to e.g.: Digium D60 so that they natively support the opus codec, or there shouldn't be much difference if the PBX does the transcoding?

Thanks!

Comment: Might be worth asking at https://serverfault.com/, I vote on closing as off-topic (hardware question).

Answer (score 0):

OPUS nice only if you have no g729->opus conversion.

If you have PSTN connection have no any reason do that.